# How to create ui-component and get it in custom block?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, uicomponent

In Magento 2.1.4, I created custom template in backend.

`Company/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Edit/Custom` has template `Company_Module::html/custom.phtml`.

`custom.phtml` code:

```
<div class="sample">
    ..........
</div>
```

Now I want to create a `custom_ui.xml` and set this into block. How to made it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are able to implement a ui component directly inside a .phtml file.

Implementing a ui-component to a page, is done by adding the ui-component to a layout xml file like:

`<uiComponent name="..."/>`

so if you just want to try to add some surrounding tag around your ui component, you maybe can try using a `container` layout handle around it.

Or by adding the ui-component to a child block of your current block and render the child block inside your template.

(Well meanwhile im working with 2.3.x, but i know this also works on 2.2.x ... i actually do *not* know how things were back at 2.1.x)